# remove duplicate rows based on the highest value in another column in Pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I have a pandas df like below

In below df, in index `0,1` `&` `2,3` ......`& 500,501,502` the duplicate values found in X & Y columns, and again the seconds round started with same duplicate values in X & Y column in index `1000, 1001 & 1002,1003 & ....1200,1201....` `it goes on` but with different weights in weight column.

```
index     x         y         weight
0         59.644    10.72     0.69
1         59.644    10.72     0.82
2         57.822    10.13     0.75
3         57.822    10.13     0.68
4         57.822    10.13     0.20
.
.
500       53.252    10.85     0.15
501       53.252    10.85     0.95
502       53.252    10.85     0.69
.
.
1000      59.644    10.72     0.85
1001      59.644    10.72     0.73
1002      57.822    10.13     0.92
1003      57.822    10.13     0.15
.
.
.
1200       53.252    10.85     0.78
1201       53.252    10.85     1.098
```

**My requirement**

> I would like to have my df
>   1) Avoid repeated/duplicate row values in X & Y which has weight value less 
>   than 0.60
>
> 2) But still duplicates in X & Y column repeats, So now i want to compare the weight values between duplicate rows & remove the rows which has lesser weight.
>
> 3) If I use the below code, it removes all the duplicates between x &
>   y

```
df_2.groupby(['X', 'Y'], as_index=False,sort=False)['weight'].max()
```

> But I want to compare the first occured duplicates and remove them,
>   then the 2nd, then 3rd and so on ..so that the continuity of duplicate
>   value prevails after some rows. for better understanding, please refer
>   the below required df

How the df should look like:

```
index     x         y         weight
1         59.644    10.72     0.82
2         57.822    10.13     0.75
.
.
501      53.252    10.85      0.95
.
.
1000      59.644    10.72     0.85
.
1002      57.822    10.13     0.92
.
.
1201       53.252    10.85     1.098   
.
.
```

I have tried using if statement, but the line of code increases.
I believe that there should be an alternate pythonic way which make it easier. (In-built function or using numpy)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['x', 'y'], as_index=False, sort=False)['weight'].max()`

Comment: please find the edited question, i forgot to mention some required parameters @Erfan

Comment: @Mari - Whats happen if all values per `x` and `y` group are `<0.6` ?

Comment: None of the groups of `x` & `y`, where all values not less less that 0.6.
many values falls above 0.6 may be 1 or 2 it is less than 0.6. @jezrael

Comment: @Mari - OK, so it means there is at least one value `<0.6` per group? So then `df.groupby(['x', 'y'], as_index=False, sort=False)['weight'].max()` working nice, because max value is always <0.6. Or something missing?

Comment: After his edit I understand it wont work, look at index 500 and 1200, both have the same values in x and y, so they will be treated as one group in the `groupby`. He wants to see them as two different groups. @jezrael

Comment: @Erfan - OK, so reopened.

Comment: Some groups may also have values not less than 0.6 (i.e) it has values greater than 0.6. But some groups do have. @jezrael

Comment: @Mari - Can you add/ change values in `weight` with this groups, also with expected output?

Comment: Which means whether i can change manually the group weights ???
Is that you mean ??@jezrael

Comment: @Mari - I think in sample data in question. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok ok ...I will do that- @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Erfan mentioned in comments, here is necessary grouping by helper `Series` for distinguish consecutive groups:

```
x1 = df['x'].ne(df['x'].shift()).cumsum()
y1 = df['y'].ne(df['y'].shift()).cumsum()

df = df[df.groupby([x1, y1])['weight'].transform('max') == df['weight']]
print (df)
    index       x      y  weight
1       1  59.644  10.72   0.820
2       2  57.822  10.13   0.750
6     501  53.252  10.85   0.950
8    1000  59.644  10.72   0.850
10   1002  57.822  10.13   0.920
13   1201  53.252  10.85   1.098
```

Comment: I see these types of questions more and more, people want to groupby, but handle the groups as seperate groups when they have a distance in the dataframe.